# How to set optimizer in logistic regression in the apache spark mllib with python

Tags: python, bigdata, apache-spark

I am now getting started to make some tests on apache spark mllib

```
def mapper(line):
    feats = line.strip().split(',')
    label = feats[len(feats)-1]
    feats = feats[:len(feats)-1]
    feats.insert(0,label)
    return numpy.array([float(feature) for feature in feats])

def test3():
    data = sc.textFile('/home/helxsz/Dropbox/exercise/spark/data_banknote_authentication.txt')
    parsed = data.map(mapper)
    logistic = LogisticRegressionWithSGD()
    logistic.optimizer.setNumIterations(200).setMiniBatchFraction(0.1)
    model = logistic.run(parsed)
    labelsAndPreds = parsed.map(lambda points: (int(points[0]), model.predict( points[1:len(points)]) ))
    trainErr = labelAndPreds.filter(lambda (v,p): v != p).count() / float(parsed.count())
    print 'training error = ' + str(trainErr)
```

but when I used the LogisticRegressionWithSGD as below

```
logistic = LogisticRegressionWithSGD()
logistic.optimizer.setNumIterations(200).setMiniBatchFraction(0.1)
```

it gives a error that AttributeError: 'LogisticRegressionWithSGD' object has no attribute 'optimizer'

Here is the API doc for [LogisticRegressionWithSGD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/mllib/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD) and [GradientDescent](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/mllib/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent)

Answer (score 0):

In the python API you can set these parameters when you call 'train':

```
model = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(parsed, iterations=200, miniBatchFraction=0.1)
```

The only documentation I was able to find about this was in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/mllib/classification.py)